# How to redirect to external url from apex from callout response

Tags: apex, callout, pagereference, redirect, httpresponse

I have a class from which I do a callout in apex. After the response of the callout I want to redirect the user to an external url how can I achieve this?.

I have only been able to redirect independent of the callout. In my example below I want to redirect to returnURl instead of 'https://www.goole.com'

```
public class leadgen {
    private final Lead weblead;  
    public Payment_Hub(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        weblead = (Lead)stdController.getRecord();
    }
    public PageReference saveLead() {
        try {
            insert(weblead);
            PostPayment(weblead.id); 
        }
        catch(System.DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error'));
            return null;
        }
        PageReference p = new PageReference('https://www.goole.com');
        p.setRedirect(true);
        return p;
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void PostPayment(Id LeadId) {
        //Catch is not needed since soql's cant be empty in this case 
        List<obj> ..

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        ..
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        // Parse the JSON response
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                         response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
        } else {
            System.debug('response.getBody()'+response.getBody());
            JSON payClass = JSON.parse(response.getBody());

            system.debug('returnURl: '+ payClass.links.checkout.href);
            string returnURl = payClass.links.checkout.href;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a VF page? And is the logic called on click of button?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Yes form a VF used as site external page from there I call saveLead().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all you have to ditch the future. :) Considering its a VF Page.

Split the operation in 2 chunks that can happen in independently.

1) DML

2) Callout without future.

Now define an action function that does the callout.

Apex Command Button has an `oncomplete` attribute which invokes JS when the result of an AJAX update request completes on the client.

So on click of [commandbutton](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm) you save the record, and then oncomplete calls the [actionfunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) which does the callout. As you have broken the transaction by coming back to JS . You can then do callout as its a different transaction.

To end user, it would just look like a normal button click.

EDIT : On googling i got an example of this on this [blog](https://ashishkeshari.com/index.php/2017/05/11/dml-before-apex-callouts-using-salesforce-ajax/).

Comment: Do You have an example of this. 1st I tried without the future but get an authorisation required error in my site page. I checked all the permissions on Guest profile. 2nd Still how do I do the redirect from the result of the callout?

Comment: You sure you got authorisation error and not uncommited work pending error?

Comment: Yes shure If  I directry us the same call I get you error. I saw you example an think I got it thanks!